# TX/RX on Android serial port using a Phonegap cordova plugin

Tags: serial-port, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I need a phonegap plugin that will talk to the serial port on an Android device. It looks like everything out there is out of date. Anyone know of one out there that can be used?